# Make the inbox first in the dropdown

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ default to “inbox” rather than “hot questions”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86342/can-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-default-to-inbox-rather-tha)

When going to the top left corner, I usually want to check my inbox for older messages that I didn't get a chance to respond to. For me at least, the **hot questions** tab is something I never check; I'm only active on 3 sites, so most of the questions there are of no interest to me. I'm much more interested in messages that are addressed to me than I am of questions on topics I might not know anything about.

Also, in the **all sites** tab, shouldn't there be an indication as to what sites I actually have an account on? Maybe those sites should be separated in some way from the others.

Comment: @Kevin wow, thanks for finding that one :).