# Can I turn off "Hot Network Questions"?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I love the "Hot Network Questions"... so much that I am looking up *real work* and the next thing I know 45 minutes have gone by and I have not even read what I came for.  This happens multiple times a day -- you can do the math.

Is there a way to turn them off or hide them from my normal view?

---

Sorry, I just found [Disable hot questions to prevent distraction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110528/disable-hot-questions-to-prevent-distraction?rq=1) (which was highly downvoted???) And it sounds like my answer is "fat chance".  Thanks.  I guess this can be closed/deleted.

Comment: Regarding what you found it's not relevant anymore, part of the old top bar that is no more. The hot questions in the sidebar are pretty recent change. :)

Comment: Use AdBlock as mentioned here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223603/139701