# Provide option to disable distracting Hot Network Questions

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

The "Hot Network Questions" sidebar is a really nice toy when I browse Stack Exchange for fun, but it never helped me when working and using the serious Q&A aspect of, say, Stack Overflow.

It is purposefully distracting, luring one to other corners of Stack Exchange. One quarter of (my) screen estate covered by off-topic (by definition) links and texts. They draw the eye especially since there is hardly any visual separation between them and the very useful "Related" topics sidebar.

I usually skim right over "Related" and suffer some serious mental gear clashing before I realize that I had "gone too far".

Would it be possible to add a button to deactivate those links? Maybe just for an hour or two?
Optimally a setting which allows to specify a time one doesn't want to be distracted. Like 9-5 on Workdays or similar.

*Edit* for clarification:
I am not looking for some browser hack or plugin or advice on mental disorders. This is just a feature request.

Comment: @rene: This is a feature request.

Comment: The second one is a marked as a duplicate to the first one, and the third one's answer is completely external to the site (browser hack). Again: This is a feature request.

Comment: That the answer is external doesn't really matter does it? It is still the same feature request.... you can down vote the existing answer, or put a bounty on the question to give it more attention. If you really think your FR  is different from the ones currently chosen as dup-target you need to clarify in your question why they are not a correct duplicate.

Comment: Since http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110528 is a good enough match, with a rather nonsensical answer, could you please remove the other ones that aren't?