# Hot questions of a specific site

Tags: feature-request, support, hot-questions

Is there anyway to see the list of recent hot questions of only a specific SE site?

[image]

I am looking for a way to see only those hot questions that appear in the "**hot questions**" tab of StackExchange menu. The **[hot](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot)** questions tab of each site contains lots of questions that may never show up in that menu.

**Update**: If there is no such feature yet, one way of quickly implementing it is to have an RSS feed for [questions that recently have been awarded [image: favorite questions] badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/33/favorite-question) or any of the following badges:

[image: good questions]
[image: great questions]
[image: nice questions]
[image: notable questions]
[image: popular questions]

Comment: LOL @ "Cortez thinks I'm gay, will it affect my chances to date women?"  -->   and it's *gaming* ? So confused....  You know, come to think of it, yes Meysam, good suggestion here. Good one.

Comment: While we're filling out our Christmas lists, I think an option to only see hot questions from sites that you're a member of would be nice.  I know this undercuts hot's utility as a discovery mechanism, but I personally am not, nor will I ever be, interested in questions from e.g. movies.SE.

Comment: @K.G.: It makes more sense to do it the other way--blacklist sites from the supercollider. That way newer sites can still catch your eye. Though [a normalisation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126860/178438) would be nice.