# Bringing an unanswered question to the first page by applying little changes to it

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Couple of weeks ago I asked [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125798/172611) here on meta which has not been answered yet. Someone even started a bounty on it but still there was no answer. Now I have decided to bring this question up to the first page regularly by editing it with a very minor change (like adding or removing a dot). Is this considered a bad practice?

Comment: If you are not adding additional information then yes - it is a bad practice.  If your post did not receive enough attention perhaps it is simply not interesting to people...

Comment: @Lix I have already tried to add additional information to it as much as I could.

Comment: Consider the possibility that there is no answer... Your question is very specifically about something you wish the site/family of sites did (which it currently doesn't do).

Comment: @Oded Can I add a `feature-request` tag to it?

Comment: @Meysam - That certainly would be OK.

Comment: Adding that will run the risk of a [status-declined]... just saying :)

Comment: @Lix How is it risky?

Comment: Well the [se] team is in charge of authorizing or denying feature requests.  They will now have to respond to your feature request with [one of the six](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/172936) `status` tags...

Comment: @Lix That's a good thing then! :)

Comment: What you're describing is an attempt to game the system (not suggesting you have any bad intent, but that's basically what you've described), and that would tend to be looked poorly on by users and mods. I wouldn't recommend it. As other commenters have said - If you can add more detail then that's great and encouraged, but making trivial changes just to "bump" your question is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is considered bad practice.

Look at the question and see if you can *add* details to it - the more the better. Try to see what would cause it to not be answered in the first place and try to resolve that.

Comment: And what happens if I do it? Will there be any sort of punishment or any kind of warning from a moderator?

Comment: @Meysam - With enough edits (I believe 8) by yourself, the question will be converted to CW. It _may_ show up on the radar of the moderators.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a bad practice. You can add more details to your question and make it intensive.

But still if you don't get much attention, (Just a suggestion, and please correct me if I am wrong). delete the question and re-ask it. It will be top on the list once again.