# Isn't the "hot questions" list universal?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-button, hot-questions

While chatting about the hot questions list (in the multicollider), we realized that I have [50 items](http://pastebin.com/Abr6FLve) in my list (with lowest hotness score 10), while [tpg2114](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/6634/tpg2114) has only 30 (with lowest hotness 13)

For reference, [tpg2114](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/6634/tpg2114) has the following [30 items](http://pastebin.com/h36hgNSk) which has changed since the chat but still only shows 30.

[(relevant chat here)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7677881#7677881)

Isn't the hot questions list universal? Or are there some parts which are user-specific? If so, what are they?

Comment: Good one. Could be that the list only shows sites you're a member of, but I haven't been able to find confirmation of that.

Comment: @MrLister: Nope. tpg isn't a member of judaism.se, but it shows up in his hot questions list. Anyway, the intention behind the hot questions list is to [promote sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126860/178438) as much as it is to promote posts.

Comment: Can you two compare what you get from [this request](http://stackexchange.com/genuwine)? I currently get [this](http://pastebin.com/9C8LckBG) and using my loyal [shadow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/206610) I can confirm it's exactly the same for two different accounts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of items in the MitliCollider is taken from the setting on the ["Hot Questions" tab on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/questions). If you set it to 50 items there, you also get 50 items in the MultiCollider.

If you don't set that option, you get the default 30 items.

Comment: I see nowhere where I can change this setting on the linked page.