# Can we customize or filter hot questions and site list in the StackExchange menu?

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filtering “hot” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions)

The list of StackExchange sites is growing, this is a good thing!

However, there are now more Q&A sites appearing in the list of sites and the list of hot questions under the Multi-Collider Super DropDown menu.

I'd like some way to filter out the sites I don't frequent, so that they don't show up at all. Can this be done?

Comment: See also [Can you filter out certain SE sites from the hot questions list?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90885/155585), asked about an hour later than your question.

Comment: @Hendrik It seems waiting an extra hour to ask would have somehow gotten more attention... Odd.

Comment: It appears Jeff has answered this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions/89364#89364

Comment: Odd indeed. And good that you posted the link!