# Can you filter out certain SE sites from the hot questions list?

Tags: feature-request, filtering, hot-questions

Is it possible to filter out Stack Exchange sites from the hot questions list?

Comment: Aww, the question lost its personality now that I didn't get to mention which SE sites I don't care about :)

Comment: Funnily enough, almost the same question has been asked an hour earlier: [Can we customize or filter hot questions and site list in the StackExchange menu?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90879/155585) (Or is that one different, @Sam?)

Comment: Jeff's answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions/89364#89364

Comment: I also would like [those sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/90885/1) + [Christianity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104923/block-christianity-exchange-in-hot-questions-list), Islam, Bible to not appear in my hot list, while others may not like distracting questions about Gaming or whatever else prevents them from staying focused.

Answer (score 10):

Not likely.

But you could using a Greasemonkey script.  Not the most complete set of features but it does what you want.  Just update the `blacklist` and `whitelist` within the script to suit your needs.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Filter Hot SE questions
// @namespace      http://stackoverflow.com/users/390278
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/*
// @include        http://*.superuser.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://*.serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://stackapps.com/*
// @include        http://*.stackapps.com/*
// @include        http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include        http://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @include        http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    function embedScript(id, main, globalFunctions) {
        var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
        scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
        scriptElement.id = id;
        var name, content = "";
        if (globalFunctions) {
            for (name in globalFunctions) {
                if (globalFunctions.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    content = content + name + "=(" + globalFunctions[name].toString() + "());\n";
                }
            }
        }
        content = content + "(" + main.toString() + "());";
        scriptElement.textContent = content;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
        return scriptElement;
    }

    embedScript("filter-hot-se-questions", function () {
        var blacklist = [
            "english.stackexchange.com",
        ];
        var whitelist = [
            "stackoverflow.com",
        ];

        $(".genu").click(function () {
            var retryCount = 0;
            const retryMax = 3;

            function tryFilter() {
                var $query = $("#seContainerHot>.itemBox").filter(function () {
                    var $link = $(this).find(".siteLink");
                    var site = $link.attr("href").match(/:\/\/(?:www\.)?(.[^\/:]+)/)[1];
                    return !$.inArray(site, blacklist) && $.inArray(site, whitelist);
                });

                if ($query.length > 0) {
                    returyCount = 0;
                }

                $query.hide();

                if (retryCount++ < retryMax) {
                    window.setTimeout(tryFilter, 1000);
                }
            }

            window.setTimeout(tryFilter, 1000);
        });
    });
}());
```

Comment: Well, isn't the problem with this that you won't get any other hot questions to replace the ones that your greasemonkey script removes. You could end up with a nearly empty hot questions list if you are only interested in a few SE sites.

Comment: @Sam: Naturally.  But that's a StackExchange "feature."  It's how most things work here anyway.  A fixed amount of content is downloaded and uninteresting items are merely hidden away.  e.g., hiding questions with uninteresting tags.  It would have to make another request to get more content (something on my todo list once I figure out how to do that).

Comment: Well, wouldn't it make more sense to do the filtering server-side?

Comment: @Sam: IMHO yes of course.  However we can only wish that the SE team does that but they don't.  But I don't blame em.  With the traffic they have to deal with every day, I can understand why they'd want to offload some of that work.

Comment: there is also the problem that not all users necessarily have control of the pc they are reading from

Comment: There is also the problem that users may not use a Greasemonkey-capable browser.