# Blocking certain stack exchange sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filtering "hot" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions)
>   [Can you filter out certain SE sites from the hot questions list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90885/can-you-filter-out-certain-se-sites-from-the-hot-questions-list)

I really like the widget on the top left - the drop-down that lets you know what's happening on the rest of the network.

However, is it possible to block certain sites from showing up in the results?

Comment: possible dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90885/can-you-filter-out-certain-se-sites-from-the-hot-questions-list and/or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions

Comment: Total dupe. I did search and couldn't find owt. Thanks for highlighting - am reading it now.

Comment: The widget has [a (or rather several) name(s)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/66838#66838).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [feature request for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions) was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined):

> Please note that the intent here is to *explicitly* expose you to the most interesting questions from across the network, whether you have accounts on those sites or not.
>
> edit: at the time I wrote the above, we did not have German, Japanese, or Judaism -- I am more sympathetic to the "this isn't even in a language I can read!" argument.

#### Similar Questions

- [Can you filter out certain SE sites from the hot questions list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90885/can-you-filter-out-certain-se-sites-from-the-hot-questions-list)
- [Block Christianity Exchange in hot questions list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104923/block-christianity-exchange-in-hot-questions-list)

Comment: That's a shame. I don't want to see questions from christianity.stack or english.stack. As a native English speaking rationalist/atheist, these sites have nothing to offer me and I find their presence in my list irritating.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Don't quote just half of Jeff's answer. Clearly, in his edit he was more sympathetic to the request.

Comment: @yoda: He was, but only with respect to content in different languages.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Judaism is not a language. Christianity is now the new "I don't want to see X".

Comment: Out of curiosity, @Iain, why do you find their presence irritating? Is is because those slots could be filled with content more of interest to you, and you feel the opportunity cost?

Comment: @yoda: There are several posts on Judaism whose titles are mostly in Hebrew. I interpreted his comment as referring to that.

Comment: @Michael Becuse those sites have nothing to offer me. If I see a question discussing something from the bible as if it was fact, I can't help but feel distracted and a little annoyed.