# Block networks from appearing in the 'Hot Network Questions' list

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hot-questions, filtering

I see this was asked a couple of times about three years ago and at the time the feature request was apparently denied:

- [Filtering "hot" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions)
- [Can you filter out certain SE sites from the hot questions list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90885/can-you-filter-out-certain-se-sites-from-the-hot-questions-list)
- [Blocking certain stack exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105159/blocking-certain-stack-exchange-sites)

Is this still the case? If so, why? I have precisely *zero* interest in having certain questions polluting a list that I might actually find useful if I could at least tailor it a bit to my needs.

Comment: `var search = "fantasy";
$("#hot-network-questions").find("li").filter(function(){
 return $("div:first",this)[0].title.toUpperCase().indexOf(search.toUpperCase()) > -1;
}).remove();` At the very least, you could use a user script. Just enter the search text (sorry fantasy, just an example).

Comment: Since this is a feature-request, the negative votes indicate that those users feel that this feature should not be implemented. It is just how meta handles feature-requests specifically so try to keep that in mind. As for the actual request, it would require quite a lot of actual implementation from the team, and I think that since so much is required to do this, it would have gone over a little better if you had included more details about what this feature would have actually looked like.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @TravisJ, I wasn't aware downvotes were used to that effect here. My question was really if this decision had changed rather than discussing a possible implementation. In any case I believe it would be pretty simple: just add in the settings a list of networks and let the user select which ones to block. Not sure why you say this would be so much trouble/time/effort.

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/filter-hot-network-questions-by-excluding-sites