# Don't show me hot questions I can't understand

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, languages

There are already many sites **about** foreign languages, and sites **in** foreign languages are starting (Stack Overflow in Portugese).

Because of it, the hot questions tab is often filled with questions most folks here won't understand.

Let us setup in profile, which languages we know at least good enough to generally understand the text in that language. Don't show to us the questions from the sites in/about other languages.

Comment: How are they different from the Math site?

Comment: @UphilLuge assuming you've learned math in school, at least you know the symbols...

Answer (score 2):

There already is a [foreign language filter for the hot list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94526/160551):

> Questions without a sufficient amount of English are now not only excluded from the stackexchange.com homepage (that's what you see in the “hot questions” tab of the multicollider), but also from Stack Exchange tweets and SE 2.0 ads.
>
> Currently, the basic criteria for the English threshold* are:
>   a) The title has 2 or fewer non-English words (ignoring proper nouns)
>   b) The body is 75% English or more, by length
>
> <sup>*</sup> only applies to certain sites, like german, judaism, and japanese

Comment: Even if question is in English, it's still about the language I don't know. For example, that 25% in Japanese site are the characters I have now idea what they are about ;) And the problem will arise, when we'll have a few Portugese-speaking sites and users who don't know English, but still see hot questions in English only.