# What questions are excluded from the hot-question list based on content?

Tags: support, hot-questions

I was wondering whether the conditions listed in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94526/167500) to an old question are still applicable.

What is the full list of criteria a question's content (body and title) must satisfy so that it has a chance to appear in the hot-question list — currently?