# Portuguese question in the Hot Network Questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions, languages

There is a filter to exclude non-English questions from the Hot Network Questions list. I'm not sure if the criteria for a question being English are still the same as in [this eleven year old answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94526/295232)

> a) The title has 2 or fewer non-English words (ignoring proper nouns)
> b) The body is 75% English or more, by length

but today it failed for [Por que Brasil em frances se escreve com E? Brésil](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/9567/1643) on Portuguese.SE. Comparing the Hot Network Questions for [Portuguese.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/portuguese/query/1693072/hot-network-questions-on-a-single-site) with [Spanish.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/1693072/hot-network-questions-on-a-single-site) or [Italian.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/italian/query/1693072/hot-network-questions-on-a-single-site) seems to suggest the filter is not enabled for Portuguese.SE; all sites regularly have questions not in English, but only on Portuguese.SE they qualify for HNQ.

Comment: Yeah Portuguese is the newest, so they simply did not click the button to activate the filter there just yet. Maybe at some point in the future, who knows. :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've updated the site setting on Portuguese Language to use the English title filter as the other language sites do. This should be active the next time the  Hot Network Question list gets recreated, which is about every 10-15 minutes.