# filtering out SE sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filtering “hot” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions)

Just as with tags I have options to have favorites and ignored ones, I would like similar functionality with SE sites.

Ignoring a site would mean, that questions from that site would not appear in my hot questions, nor in `all sites` drop-down.

EDIT: not a duplicate. The other question was asked and answered before non-English SE sites where introduced.

Also, a question "is it possible?" with answer "no" is not duplicate of a feature request.

Comment: And: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90885/can-you-filter-out-certain-se-sites-from-the-hot-questions-list http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90879/can-we-customize-or-filter-hot-questions-and-site-list-in-the-stackexchange-menu

Comment: @random: how can question "is it possible" with answer "no" be duplicate to a **feature request** to actually enable it?

Comment: You can also take your duplicate pick from the other links posted shortly around the new language specific sites

Comment: @random: which are all "closed as duplicate" by you with reference to same question (the pre-non-English sites one).

Comment: Don't forget [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93535/hot-questions-inability-to-filter-sites-and-now-german-questions-too-much) if you want to talk about non-English sites, and filtering them from hot questions and the Stack Exchange dropdown. ♪