# In Hot-Questions, groups seem to repeat. How about a left/right-button?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

<sub>Also inspired by ["Hot Network Questions" randomizes too much when navigation in browser history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229052/hot-network-questions-fluctuate-too-much) and [Websockets break caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228587/websockets-break-caching).</sub>

I have the feeling that there is a limited number of question-groups that change upon each page-reload/history-navigation, with each group consisting of a fixed set of questions.

Would it be desirable to add navigation there (`next` / `previous`)?

At the moment, this could also serve as a quick-fix for the problems described in above mentioned questions.