# Why does clicking twice on Show/Hide excerpts refreshes "Hot Network Questions" on the right side panel

Tags: discussion, design, hot-questions, new-nav

I am currently participated in testing the new navigation. I just saw Sklivvz ♦ post [Improving our navigation, the next iteration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/improving-our-navigation-the-next-iteration) and thought of giving a try. I love the new expanded layout view and the tab pinning. This is a great improvement. Excellent job!!

Upon switching back n forth between the **Show** and **Hide** **excerpts tabs**, I clicked "Hide excerpts" twice by accident. The posts results shown below were fine, nothing changed. The *only* change I noticed was the refresh of **Hot Network Questions** on the right side panel whereas the **Frequently Asked** above it remained unchanged.

Here is the screenshot for Hide excerpts:

> [image]

The same behavior (as for the *Hot Network Questions* goes) for the "Show excerpts" tab too. I wonder what causes the refresh to Hot Network Questions? Does this belongs to [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) category?

Comment: *Normal behavior* would effectively belong to "status-bydesign" category...

Comment: @Mat'sMug that's right... didn't think of it.... let me remove it

Comment: comment was removed and added into my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a considerable amount of discussion already in the [hot-questions](/questions/tagged/hot-questions) list. I have read few of them and I can tell you that this "Hot Network Questions" topic is *really hot* and I don't want to get myself burned by adding more noise to it. I will stick to my concern here.

Based on the following three posts:

1. [Ease up on the Hot Network Question Randomness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222991/ease-up-on-the-hot-network-question-randomness/222993) -- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
2. [What changed in the Hot Questions sidebar algorithm?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218247/what-changed-in-the-hot-questions-sidebar-algorithm/218248)
3. [What is the Goal of “Hot Network Questions”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions)

I would like to **conclude** that:

"Hot Network Questions" list **will refresh** whenever there is a on page activity that makes a server request. In my case, I was clicking on the "Hide excerpts", so the server request was made and that is the reason "Hot Network Questions" listing was getting updated everytime. So, it belongs to [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) category.

But, I do like to point out one good suggestion made by @200_success in his answer to post: [Improving our navigation, the next iteration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/improving-our-navigation-the-next-iteration/261336#261336). Here is the excerpt/relevant part of it:

> The "Show/hide excerpts" widget acts more like two buttons than one
>   toggle. Clicking on the already-activated mode, instead of toggling
>   the mode, refreshes the Hot Network Questions list, which enhances the
>   mystery of what the widget is for.

Basically, it should behave like a toggle. Once one is pressed/activated then it should be disabled. No more actions can be performed on it. This will not make a server request and thus no refreshing of "Hot Network Questions" list.