# New Navigation UI: Lost 'Answered' in question list

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

In the new navigation UI, every entry in a questions list seems to be either 'asked' or 'modified'. This seemed odd to me so I opened a new SO session in a private window that wasn't going to read my new navigation UI cookie option and sure enough, there are 'asked', modified' and 'answered' categories at the least (may be more that I am unfamiliar with).

Edit: My original narrative may have been unclear. This is what I am referring to in the old UI.

[image: New NAV UI lacks Answered]

If I respond to a question, I have posted a potential answer (such as it may be). I have not 'modified' the question. In the new Nav UI, the 'Answered' designation appears to have been supplanted by 'Modified' in every case even when no edit to the question exists.

Comment: As for the Show Excerpts and Hide Excerpts be a single toggle button goes, it has been asked [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/improving-our-navigation-the-next-iteration/261336#261336) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261319/why-does-clicking-twice-on-show-hide-excerpts-refreshes-hot-network-questions/261384#261384)

Comment: under new navigation we have "newest" (for asked) and "recently active" (for "modified"). Just to let you know that "recently active" is replacement for old "active" tab.

Comment: +1 for the "answered" which should be there. It's definitely missing. I can see it on Meta.SE "recently active" tab. See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, the view used for displaying the expanded list (including excerpts) was re-using the view that was previously only ever shown on the `/questions/tagged/{tag}?sort=active` tab, which [never implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260915/why-are-all-posts-in-active-tab-displayed-as-modified) the asked/answered status display (kudos to @HackerKarma), as it was never visible on the home page.

Both of those issues will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: m0sa OP is talking about new-nav on StackOverflow.com See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive where everything is "modified" whereas on Meta.SE http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive it has "modified", "asked", "answered"

Comment: ah, was only looking at SE... that is indeed weird, looking harder :)

Comment: No problem... don't just look hard but work hard :) Please update answer with your findings... You got a good "bug" to squash here... Have fun!

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for the mention but MANY thanks to you for getting this fixed...