# An HNQ that's 21 days old?

Tags: bug, hot-questions

[This question appears on the HNQ list right now](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/29345/16670) (I've posted a screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/735yj.png), with the quetion I mentioned, circled in yellow, in case you wanted to see it).

What surprised me was that the question was 21 days old. This is something that I thought was impossible. In July 2020 I asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions#comment1174450_61343) if anyone's ever seen an HNQ more than 4 days old and never go a reply.

I understand that the exact HNQ criteria are not publicly available, and that only an approximation was given to us (and this totally makes sense, because otherwise people could cheat the system). However, what I'm seeing today seems to either be a bug or quite a major change to the HNQ requirements, which would be the relaxing of the "maximum 3-days" criterion. Knowing about this change wouldn't make it any easier for people to cheat to get their questions in HNQ as far as I can see, so I think it's appropriate to ask about it.

**For the record, I'm not saying that this change is a good thing or a bad thing, I'm just curious if I'm seeing a bug or a fundamental change to how new a question needs to be in order to enter HNQ!**

Before asking this, I did look for similar questions, for example by looking at the latest questions in the [hot-questions](/questions/tagged/hot-questions) tag, but couldn't seem to find anything about this asked before.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I don't see the question on the [full list of HNQs](https://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I, likewise, just checked and it's not in the current full HNQ's list.

Comment: It became a HNQ on the same day it was asked, November 28 (and I vaguely remember seeing it in the list a while ago). Is it possible that you were looking at a page you loaded a while ago, or your browser loaded a cached version? I'll bet the other questions there are similarly old; the one I checked was.

Comment: @Catija perhaps it would be more appropriate to close this as "not reproducible" rather than as a duplicate? Also, my question itself already has a link to the question you re-directed it to in the dupe, and it's not really correct that "this question already has answers" in the other question.

Comment: @Laurel [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMSSD.png) taken right now, which shows that I edited [this question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1719/5) 32 minutes ago, which you can verify yourself, and the HNQ is right there in the same screenshot!

Comment: Your question is about how a question that is 23 days old could be on the HNQ list and you seem to think the triggers are secret. The duplicate explains that those statements are incorrect and explains exactly how the list works.

Comment: @user1271772 I suppose the cache of hot network questions could have been out of date even while the rest of the site was fine. Even still, it does seem like a bug that you got a list of the HNQs from several weeks ago (all the ones I checked became HNQs November 30th or earlier).

Comment: @Tyberius what is the likelihood of the cache being ~20 days out of date?

Comment: 72 hour hard limit: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/282094 - Formula: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/282094

Comment: @Rob can you explain why the formula didn't work in these cases? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358924/391772

Comment: user1271772, [That is a different bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358924/282094), for which you are not satisfied with the comments replying to your answer.  [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374276/282094) (above), which is on-topic in this comment section, [I **voted to reopen**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/81448). --- Unless I know it is **not** a bug then I can't explain it, since I agree that the duplicate doesn't apply, that it's a new bug or that the dupe is incorrect, about all I can do from the review queue is ReOpen; someone else might answer.

Comment: @Rob Thanks. My question was closed in only 7 minutes on a Sunday and by only one vote, which I think is highly unusual for a question like this (I've see *way* worse take *far* longer to get closed). I've been told that the dupe "explains exactly how the list works" [but the output of the given formula does not match the actual hotness score](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59937077#59937077).

Comment: Apparently [the complaint started years ago](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7327664#7327664) (that the formula doesn't *work*), [resulting in a **different** complaint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352779/282094) being filled. The above is "how did it exceed 72 hours", I agree (as far as we know) that shouldn't happen. Thus, the reopen vote (and [comment pointing this out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374276/an-hnq-thats-21-days-old?noredirect=1#comment1247518_374276)). Note that [exits are not annotated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324645/282094).