# Remove/downweight closed questions in "hot" question sort

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, closed-questions, hot-questions

The [current algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4766/167457) for hot questions does not take into account whether a question was closed.  Given that closed questions are typically off-topic or low quality, IMO they should receive significantly less weight in the algorithm.  Quite often on the smaller sites, egregiously off-topic questions attract a flurry of attention that pushes them near the top of the hot list.  Once the question is closed, views rapidly plummet.  Having the "hot" list polluted by closed questions makes it less useful for finding out what others are *still* looking at and talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a misconception here -- closing does not mean "get this off my screen ASAP", **closing means, "this question should be re-evaluated by the community".**

That is, it should be edited, improved and salvaged if at all possible.

Suppressing a question the very instant it is closed would not serve this purpose.

I'd also argue that, as you said,

> Once the question is closed, views rapidly plummet

So there is "enough" evaluation of closed questions, but suppressing them further would not be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but in that case, what should be done with questions that are clearly off-topic posted by users that are blatantly disregarding the site's FAQ?

Comment: if it is *radically* off topic, like "why is the sky blue?" being posted on Stack Overflow, flag it and indicate it should be deleted as actively harmful to the site.