# Hide Hot Questions?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button, hot-questions

Why hide a [hot question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/hot-questions/info)?

- You've read it.
- You're not interested.
- You want to see more hotness.

How?

- Add an 'X' beside each hot question.

Comment: Easier said then done.

Comment: @JonH Always :) - One possibility: Keep 'X'ed questions in cookies and request more when needed.

Comment: @monkeymatrix: my interest in the Hot Questions list peaked shortly after it was introduced.

Comment: Especially since certain "Hot" questions stick in the list for *days*...

Comment: @Briguy37 - It's definetly more complex then that, and storing such a thing in a cookie is not a good idea.  The minute those cookies are cleared your questions come up again.  It's not a good design model.

Comment: @JonH - So it works, but you have to re-'X' questions if you delete your cookies.  Is that really "not a good design model"?

Comment: Yes its really not a good design model, you shouldn't store something like a hot question in a cookie.

Comment: @JonH - To clarify, the ids of the questions you no longer wish to see would be stored in a cookie, not the questions themselves.  You'd then retrieve those id's via JavaScript and filter out your 'Hot Questions' results based on them.  If you don't have enough hot questions to display, you'd request more with an AJAX call.  Since these id's are neither crucial to keep (id's from days ago will rarely get used, if ever), nor memory-intensive (an id is small), I truly don't understand why it is a bad idea to store them in a cookie.  Thus, will you please explain your point?

Comment: related: [Hide questions I downvoted from my Hot Questions view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191572/hide-questions-i-downvoted-from-my-hot-questions-view) - which yields the benefit of storing the "uninterestingness" in a downvote, though one might of course want to hide unvoted questions sometimes as well

Comment: +1.  I would prefer to hide the "Hot Network Questions" section completely.

Comment: @phs - I too would prefer to hide the entire list; I find it incredibly distracting.

Comment: @Superstringcheese That's really easy client-side actually if it really bothers you. Just set up a userscript for the site that runs `document.getElementById('hot-network-questions').style.display="none";`

Comment: There is a duplicate of this question with some other interesting solutions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222721/how-to-avoid-hot-network-questions-on-the-sidebar

Answer (score 28):

Yes please. Today a question is on the hot questions list that I do not want to see any more. It is a single word request (not my fave by any means) for a particular kind of nasty crime. I won't ask for a word filter to exclude questions with "rape" in the title, but I would really like to be able to x this question on one site and not have it offered to me again. Like we do with Facebook ads.

Comment: Separate from the broader request above, I'd like to ensure we have a way (at least as a human-excpetion-handling) to suppress posts with triggers or that generally are appropriate on-site, but not for a broader audience that hasn't elected to go there. I don't like seeing that question title either.  I'm editing it to mitigate a little, but will look into an override option.

Comment: @Jaydles: someone's gonna have to make a feature request for awarding bounties to comments or edits :) Until then, +6 in spirit!

Comment: @NickStauner (and Kate), just FYI, we're implementing a *very* short blacklist in the next week or two.  Initially, it'll just suppress posts with a few trigger terms in the titles from hot questions, but the team will be able to add terms as we encounter posts that cause distress, etc.

Comment: @Jaydles thanks! much appreciated!

Comment: @KateGregory, no thanks needed - it was bothering me, too, but your highlighting it spurred me to actually try to find a quick solution, so thank you!

Comment: Just FYI: the blacklist @Jaydles was talking about went live a couple weeks ago.

Comment: Maybe https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-hot-network-question/jommfgnflipjalbpbgcfghdpoeijpoab can help you out.

Answer (score 23):

Ideally, this is how I want this to look like:

> [image]

Which will result in:

> [image]

The setting will be remembered across all sites, i.e. if you hide on arqade, it wil be hidden on Stack Overflow as well and vice versa.

Comment: Hot Network Questions are very distracting. Just being able to toggle them visible or hidden would save many of us hours per week in lost focus. I don't want to have to use adblock because I use multiple machines, and can't reliably install plugins. Also, I see the HNQ as something which reduces the total value of SE, even if it boosts traffic to newer SE sites.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo regarding your last sentence: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5289644#5289644

Comment: Thanks, @Shadow . I thought it was something like that. I want it to be an opt-in/opt-out rather than a permanent fixture though.

Answer (score 21):

I personally would like to remove particular sites (namely Movies and Sci-Fi/Fantasy) from the Hot Questions because they frequently contain spoilers.

Comment: +1.  A problem exacerbated for book readers by the fact that "The Winds of Winter" has not yet been released....  >:(

Answer (score 15):

As long as this isn't implemented: If you're using Firefox here's two ways to disable:

**Either** get [Element Hiding Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/elemhidehelper/) for [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/). Choose "Select an element to hide" and click on the Hot questions:

[image]

**or** [find your profile folder](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) and in the `chrome` directory of the profile directory, create the file `userContent.css` with the following content:

```
#hot-network-questions {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: For Chrome users: have a look at Stylish extension with  https://userstyles.org/styles/98190/hide-stack-exchange-hot-network-questions

Comment: It works also with GreaseMonkey

Comment: how to unhide element that is hidden using element-hider?

Comment: Also works with AdBlock for Chrome.

Comment: I had to restart FF 57 for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

Based on this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234613/230844), this is how I set up my Firefox `userContent.css` file so that they're blurred by default still, but I can mouse hover over to unblur, when I'm interested in a distraction.

[image]

```
#hot-network-questions {
  filter: blur(5px);
}

#hot-network-questions:hover {
  filter: - blur(0px); !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on this and [Kate's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231252/215645), I would like to see this:

1. Filtering questions that match tags per Stack if I have an account there (e.g., I put the [android] tag on the normal SO, and it is highlighted, while [ios] is filtered out.) Similar to [Almo's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233996/215645), but it is based on a wider user preferences.
2. At least have an option to hide the right sidebar, maybe even per area (not only just for the Network Questions, but for the Linked and Related as well; in some cases, it is annoying to see them) or per question (with some HTML manipulation, this could be done easily).