# Hide questions I downvoted from my Hot Questions view

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, hot-questions

Some questions deemed "hot" turn out to be not only uninteresting to me but actively bad (as a current example, take [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454333/can-the-golden-ratio-accurately-be-expressed-in-terms-of-e-and-pi)). After I downvoted such a question, it should no longer show up in my view of hot questions.

**edit** Please note this suggestion differs from [Hide Hot Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166652/hide-hot-questions) in using downvotes instead of a new-to-be-implemented "mark-as-uninteresting" mechanism. This request here simply uses downvotes (which may have been cast independently of the hot-question list).

Comment: related, but different by a manual "hide button": http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166652/146482

Comment: I can see why you might not find that particular (or any other) question interesting. But just for my curiosity, why do you think that question is 'actively bad'? You think its mere presence brings down the quality of Math.SE? I find that hard to believe. I'm the opposite of a math expert, but it looks OK to me.

Comment: @CodyGray Translated to SO, that question is similar to "What names can I give a variable", and every answer lists _one_ possibility - so yes, I think this specific question actively lowers math.SE's quality - just look at the [highest voted answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/454344/163) - there exists a simple formula for the golden ratio, but expressing it with other constants is just artificial

Comment: Fair enough. Although I couldn't help but notice the [soft-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) tag while I was there. It looks like Math.SE has slightly relaxed standards compared to some of our other sites. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Well, the top-rated question there, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/can-i-use-my-powers-for-good, is a great example what that tag is good for; but personally I dislike questions à la "How to express `x` in terms of `y` although there exists the simple expression `z`?"

Comment: Pretty much every request ever to personalise the hot questions list has been status-declined, so, good luck with this one...

Comment: @AakashM Hm, maybe we should request a better [hotness formula](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) based on user feedback à la "Does this question deserve being in the hot questions list?"

Comment: __This is a legitimate feature request, please stop trying to close it.__  Just downvote it if you disagree.  [And yes, it's obviously different from the duplicate chosen.]

Answer (score 6):

Personally I'd rather see the "hot list" bite the dust entirely.

However, if it does live to die another day, I don't think this would be a useful improvement. Essentially this would be the start of a personalization algorithm such as Google uses to show different search results to different people. While such algorithms have their place, I think it would reduce the usefulness of the hotlist rather than improve it. The whole point is to see what the rest of the network thinks is interesting at the moment, not what the network things you might find interesting.

If the later feature is developed, it should be done independently from the current functionality.

Comment: Hm, the problem is that the current hotness favours questions with _many_ answers, which may indicate a question concerning many folks, but IMHO more likely indicates a question that has no well-defined answer