# How to avoid "Hot Network Questions" on the sidebar

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, hot-questions, sidebar

This may sound like a 'first world problem', but I am quite easily distracted by the 'Hot Network Questions' sidebar, as I find them quite amusing and some of them quite intellectual

But where the problem lies is that, even at work, if I google something up and find a solution on Stack Overflow, to some random problem I am working at, I (always) get distracted towards them (Hot Network Questions), and end up reading the whole Qs as well as As of that respective question, and this is adversely affecting my productivity.

Any suggestion would greatly help.

Comment: related: [Filtering “hot” questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions)

Comment: Totally agree. This is both a complaint and a compliment; I've discovered more through Hot Network Questions in a few days more than I've learned from Wikipedia in years! On the other hand, it's really tolling on the actual work I get done.

Comment: BTW, Hot Network Questions ruins rule #8 on the [Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html)

Comment: See also: [Filter "Hot Network Questions" by excluding sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/filter-hot-network-questions-by-excluding-sites)

Comment: I would like to be able to *customise what is shown* in the Hot Network Questions list. I want to block specific SE sites because, while some I find enlightening, others that have little value I nonetheless find too tempting to ignore. I guess I either need to build my willpower, or build a script...

Comment: I understand wanting to block them when at work, but I don't get all the "they're a blemish on the website" guff. If it weren't for the hot network questions, there's a lot of other SE sites I'd never have joined and a lot of useful answers I'd never have contributed.

Comment: I would really like a setting that disables "Hot Network Questions" on all StackExchange sites. Blocking them one by one is tedious, and there are a lot of them that I legitimately end up on by Googling work-related things - StackOverflow, SuperUser, ServerFault, db admins, ubuntu, computer science, Ask Different (apple), Software Engineering, Unix & Linux, Raspberry Pi...

Answer (score 165, accepted):

No further need for self control or userscripts!

As of 11 March 2019 you can hide the HNQ list from the sidebar globally by visiting your [preferences page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) and choosing "Hide Hot Network Questions", which appears in the "Sidebar" section.

[image: Hide Hot Network Question preference on user preferences page]

This was rolled out as part of a [major update to the HNQ list behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-little-less).

Comment: Now let us add this behavior for Hot Meta Posts, The Overflow Blog, and Featured on Meta.

Answer (score 313):

Adblock - add the following filter:

```
stackoverflow.com###hot-network-questions
```

or, if you need to do work on other SE sites:

```
###hot-network-questions
```

Also, if you use uBlock origin, you can simply right-click the element and click "block element" to implement the above.

You can turn it off when you want to read them later :) Also, you need not block any other ads if you want to support SO. I'm off to get my productivity back, good luck!

Comment: ^ This is exactly what I did, but was reluctant on whether I should share it with others, you know the 'ethical grounds talk' about blocking ads and etc....

Comment: Yeah...you don't have to block the other ads though. I hope if SE requires us to experience the site in it's most ADD-susceptible form though, that we as a community have a discussion about the implications. Honestly I love reading them, I just can't during the day without potentially losing my train of thought.

Comment: @wardha-Web for those who don't want to block ads, another option is to use a GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey script.

Comment: Lovely, that Adblock filter suggestion worked a treat for me just now. Thanks, Chris, that's a source of growing irritation squashed!

Comment: I find it sad that this is the only true solution, but this make your answer all the more valuable. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help! Also, I looked into [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji?hl=en) but unfortunately they don't have the appropriate functionality yet...

Comment: Thanks dude, this is exactly what I wanted.  Welcome back, productivity!!

Comment: Thanks. It would be better to be able to switch off Hot Network Questions via your account settings, but this is a pretty good option.

Comment: That's a wonderful wonderful tip. It never occurred to me that I could use Adblocker like this. I suspect that this will become more and more useful for a massive range of things.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting these filters to work: I get the error message "Failed to fetch this filter!" Any ideas?

Comment: Excellent, this worked for me. And I've never even considered installing an ad blocker before now. The Hot Network Questions were just that distracting.

Comment: Well... those wont be missed.

Comment: I've been using this tip for the last few months. It's wonderful. I now find StackOverflow so much more productive and useful: I can actually go and get stuff done, rather than get lost in another random maze of browsing. When I stray on to a site where I haven't applied it, it's kind of a shock to see this distracting nonsense.

I understand why the SE people think this is good for "growing communities" - but it's not great for the individual users.

Comment: So grateful for this answer, and it works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Can this be extended to also hide "Hot Meta Posts"?

Comment: For the uBlock users - it can be done too with the above filter too, just a bit more work to find where to input it. This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/970379/205082) describes it.

Comment: Are there false positives for this filter on another sites? Is there a list of all SE sites?

Comment: @SmitJohnth this filter is pretty specific -- while you can never be 100% sure, it's very unlikely it would block something on a non-SE site.

Comment: @becko `###sidebar > .community-bulletin.module`

Comment: My employer's intranet blocks access to the Chrome Extensions store - is there any way to install AdBlock without it?

Comment: Adding `##DIV[id="hot-network-questions"][class="module"]` to Adblock settings -> Customize Adblock -> Manually edit your features did the trick for me.

Comment: This is perfect. Hate that distractive stuff!

Comment: How do you get it to allow ads, but still block the hot network questions?

Comment: @mjs: If you're using uBlock, go to settings and click on the `3rd-party filters` tab. You can uncheck all filters but your own. (If you want to block HNQ on SO but not ads, and block ads everywhere else, I might advise using GreaseMonkey at that point.)

Comment: @Chris Ah, i was hoping for an adblock only solution. Your answer suggested you can still see ads even with adblock blocking the HNQ. Did I missinterpret. Also, getting started with GreaseMonkey sounds a whole load.... distracting :-)

Comment: It wasn't at all obvious to me how to do this in Firefox. "Tools" -> "AdBlock Plus" -> "Filter preferences..." -> "Custom Filters". Then "Add filter group" if necessary or click on an existing group, "Actions" -> "Show/hide filters", then "Add filter" and finally paste in the filter.

Comment: God bless you...  (you might also give some instructions about where to add that filter in adblock - it took a little time for me to find it).

Comment: Thank you for this filter. I reenabled adblock for *.stackexchange.com for this. I use adblock by default and whitelist favourite sites. I hope that in future I can disable HNQ in settings and whitelist stack* again...

Comment: Awesome, as soon as stackexchange allows me to turn of this directly, I'll add it to the adblock whitelist.

Comment: I was just checking the status of [Is "hotness" the best way of sorting linked questions in the sidebar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303537/is-hotness-the-best-way-of-sorting-linked-questions-in-the-sidebar) ... what am I doing here?

Comment: As an ignorant pleb with no knowledge of how Adblock works, "Block an ad on this page" -> <Click hot network questions> did the trick for me (although you have to do it again every time you visit a different stack exchange).

Comment: Safari's ADP no longer allows custom filters.

Comment: The filter `stackexchange.com,askubuntu.com,mathoverflow.net,serverfault.com,stackoverflow.com,stackapps.com,superuser.com###hot-network-questions` avoids hitting other websites.

Answer (score 116):

I think some of the answers here that suggest "Have some self control!" miss the point.

- Given: Seeing an interesting question automatically makes some brains trigger "work on that question" (umm, [citation](https://xkcd.com/356/) - you know if this describes you)
- Given: Intentionally avoiding looking at that area, or even harder, stopping the "work on that question" process, once started, requires some quantity of mental resources
- Given: mental resources are limited (for all of us) and very valuable (for many of us)

"Have more self control" is another way of saying "use some of your limited and valuable mental resources to do X".

Soo...why would you argue that StackExchange (StackOverflow is what I am on most often), that great boon to productivity everywhere (see StackOverflow [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about), which says: "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions") should force this distraction on all its users?  If I want to be distracted, I'll go to Buzzfeed (I don't).

I guess the question comes down to: does SE want to prioritize the interests of its users, or prioritize "get more questions answered, even if it means being a parasite of mental resources like Buzzfeed"?  It's a free site so I have no standing to argue that SE should prioritize my interests, but it's a question that needs to be answered.

(In closing: please allow users to choose to hide it.)

Comment: Yeah humans are deeply flawed - we are wired to be distracted. Once you recognise and work with that fact - you will have a better life and be more effective. This is certainly a situation where SE interests are deeply misaligned with users.

Comment: The hot network questions can also be [a source of film spoilers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224108/351462).

Comment: It is a mental health issue, it undermines your ability to concen

Answer (score 43):

If you use Chrome but don't want to trust a third-party extension, you can roll your own pretty easily:

1. manifest.json

   ```json
   {
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "name": "Stack exchange styles",
       "version": "0.1",
       "content_scripts": [{
           "matches": ["*://meta.stackexchange.com/*", "*://stackoverflow.com/*"],
           "css": ["style.css"]
       }]
   }
   ```
2. style.css

   ```
   #hot-network-questions { display: none; }
   ```
3. Open `chrome://extensions/`, enable "Developer mode", click on "Load unpacked extension" then select the folder containing the 2 files above.

Comment: Great if, like me, your employer blocks access to the Chrome Extensions store.

Comment: Thanks for this, it has the added bonus of quickly introducing the user to how to set up one's own Chrome Extensions.

Comment: Great ! How to do it efficiently for every websites of the stackexchange network ?

Comment: @Marine1 For a start, add `"*://askubuntu.com/*", "*://*.stackexchange.com/*"` to `matches`.

Comment: Not so great if, now like me, your employer blocks Chrome developer extensions as well...

Comment: @rleelr Lol, two years later. Keep us posted, and godspeed. *salutes*

Comment: Would it be easy to extend this to be active only at certain times of day? Or to be easily switched on and off?

Answer (score 33):

1. Install Stylus browser extension, which allows custom CSS to be run. Download link here, for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/).
2. Install [this user script](https://userstyles.world/style/8763/stackexchange-focus-hide-all-distractions), or copy paste the CSS code into Stylus.
3. Test and enjoy life without distractions.

This script hides ANYTHING distracting. eg. chat rooms, network questions, linked answers, banners. Let me know if I missed anything. It works on all Stack Exchange sites, not just Stack Overflow.

What is the advantage of this method? This is faster, because it's pure CSS, no JavaScript. And you can easily enable/disable it in 2 clicks,

[image: Click on the teal S Sylus icon. Check or uncheck "Stackexchange Focus Hide..."]

Full source code below for convenience,

```
/* ==UserStyle==
@name         Stackexchange Focus Hide All Distractions
@version      20230228.15.22
@namespace    userstyles.world/user/tinker
@description  This script hides ANYTHING distracting. eg. chat rooms, network questions, linked answers, banners. Let me know if I missed anything.

Works on all stackexchange sites not just stackoverflow.
@author       tinker
@license      No License
==/UserStyle== */

@-moz-document domain("askubuntu.com"), domain("mathoverflow.net"), domain("serverfault.com"), domain("stackapps.com"), domain("stackexchange.com"), domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("superuser.com") {
#sidebar {
    display:                none !important;
}
#mainbar, .mainbar, #questions, .question-summary, #answers, .answer {
    min-width:              728px !important;
    width:                  50% !important;
}
.summary {
    min-width:              630px !important;
    width:                  calc(100% - 120px) !important;
}
.question > table {
    width:                  100% !important;
}
.post-text, .wmd-preview, .post-editor, .wmd-input {
    min-width:              660px !important;
    width:                  100% !important;
}
.wmd-button-bar {
    min-width:              634px !important;
    width:                  100% !important;
}

#footer {
    display:                none !important;
}
.site-header--container  {
    display:                none !important;
}
.js-dismissable-hero  {
    display:                none !important;
}
#left-sidebar {
    display:                none !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Updated this. The old user scripts are not working anymore.

Comment: Since January 2017, Stylish has been spying on your internet history. https://robertheaton.com/2018/07/02/stylish-browser-extension-steals-your-internet-history/

Comment: The Stylus extension could be used as a replacement to the now spyware-enabled Stylish. It is a fork of Stylish and contains the same Undistractify StackOverflow style.

Comment: Thank you, Hot Network Questions is an abomination and this is probably the easiest solution I've encountered.

Comment: This script successfully removes Hot Network Posts using Tampermonkey.   But it no longer removes Hot Meta Posts and other yellow boxes. How do I do that?

Comment: @JosiahYoder This is a stylish/stylus userscript, typically CSS based. Why are you using Tampermonkey? isn't that javascript?

Comment: just updated this, to use Stylus extension. Script is now hosted on open source userstyles.world.com.

Answer (score 31):

For those who use [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or [TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net), you can easily create a user script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Hide Hot Network Questions 
// @namespace  http://CHANGE.TO.YOUR.WEBPAGE
// @version    0.1
// @description  Hide Hot-Network-Questions in StackExchange sites
// @match      *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match      *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match      *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match      *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match      *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match      *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match      *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @exclude    *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude    *://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude    *://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
    var bar = document.getElementById('hot-network-questions');
    if (bar) bar.style.display="none";
})();
```

Comment: Using [Stylish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish) with `#hot-network-questions { display: none }` might be even more effective.

Comment: My productivity is saved!

Comment: @IlmariKaronen That should be an answer

Answer (score 15):

One new chrome extension to rule them all. It also hides other annoying sidebars like chat!

Plus point, chrome extension allows for easy toggling.

Simply awesome!

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sidebaroverflow/lhieihmjhlbhpjkamdjfjldcapnmhddp?hl=en

[image]

Comment: Looks kinda promising, is the extension available for other browsers?

Comment: i don't think so. I didn't do a search though.

Comment: Update: this doesn't work for superUser. Only for stack overflow. BIG minus point. Now, I'm using Stylish script posted in another answer.

Comment: One nice thing about this extension is the source is available here: https://github.com/ShivanKaul/SidebarOverflow

Comment: This quadrupled my productivity :D No more "oh I know the answer to this one and I bet everyone else is wrong"

Answer (score 13):

You can use a user stylesheet on Mozilla browsers (SeaMonkey, Firefox, Camino). It does not require any installed extensions.

Open the `userContent.css` file (create if necessary) in your [profile folder's](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder) `chrome` directory, and paste the following:

```
@-moz-document domain(stackexchange.com), domain(stackoverflow.com), domain(serverfault.com) {
    #hot-network-questions {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

You will need to restart the browser for any changes to take effect.

The `userContent.css` file is tucked away inside the profile folder, which is a bit tough to find.

You can follow the [instructions for SeaMonkey](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_SeaMonkey) or [for Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox) on the Mozillazine wiki, or here's the short version:

- `~/.mozilla/seamonkey/******/chrome/userContent.css` (Unix)
- `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\SeaMonkey\Profiles\******\chrome\userContent.css` (Windows)
- `~/Library/Application Support/SeaMonkey/Profiles/******/chrome/userContent.css` (OS X)

where '`******`' is your profile's name plus a random string. You know you are in the correct directory if you see the file `userContent-example.css` there.

Comment: I can't use Firefox extensions so this solution is ideal, and seems to work fine.

Comment: This should be at the top.

Comment: For me, this required a restart of Firefox, but then worked great!

Comment: The chrome directory has to be created as well. In current version (60.0), on Unix, the file has to be in `~/.mozilla/firefox/***.default/chrome/userContent.css`

Answer (score 10):

Blocking the Hot Network Questions is one of the features of [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox).

After installing, you need to apply some settings. This is the one:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I've written [a Chrome extension to hide/filter the Hot Network Questions list](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jommfgnflipjalbpbgcfghdpoeijpoab). It hides all questions by default, or you can specify a whitelist or blacklist of sites and keywords you'd like to see.

> [image]

You can install it [from the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-hot-network-question/jommfgnflipjalbpbgcfghdpoeijpoab) or [check out the code on GitHub](https://github.com/jeremybanks/hide-hnq).

Comment: reposting from [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272128/134300) which was closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 6):

AdBlock Plus (for Chrome) offers a simple solution. Just click on the extension's icon, click Block Element and then select the Hot Networks area with the mouse (it will light up when you hover over it). That's it! The job is done.

---

**PS** - After you click the box with your mouse pointer, ABP will open a popup window where the blocked elements will be listed -

```
meta.stackexchange.com###hot-network-questions
meta.stackexchange.com##.module.tex2jax_ignore
```

Just change the first line to

```
###hot-network-questions
```

and *that will implement the fix to all SE sites*.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to Chrome extensions and need to use Internet Explorer, (for example in a corporate environment) you can create a user stylesheet (save this as a .css file):

```
#hot-network-questions {
  display: none;
}
```

For Internet Explorer, go to Tools > Internet Options > General > Accessibility. Click the check box for "Format documents using my style sheet". Browse to your style sheet and choose it. Then click OK and relaunch the browser to apply the styles.

Style sheets can be installed for other browsers via these instructions: http://webdesign.about.com/od/userstylesheets/a/aa010906.htm

Answer (score 2):

For Safari, I [searched for "CSS" on the Safari Extension](https://extensions.apple.com/?q=CSS) page at Apple. I noticed [Quickstyle](https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.canisbos.rightsizer-ZANVZTSER6).

After installation of Quickstyle, I followed [the instructions](http://canisbos.com/quickstyle#howtouse) like this:[image]

And the *Hot Network Questions* disappeared!

Thank you [Ilmari Karonen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/174699/ilmari-karonen) for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

For FireFox, there is the [*UnHot* addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unhot) which should do just that. [image: unhot logo]

Just install it to hide them.

<sub>I programmed it</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution verified for Safari that

- does not require any add-ons
- probably should work cross-browser

When on the site in question

1. Quickly open console from browser using keyboard `Cmd-Option-C`  (altho you get more window than nec.)
2. Enter the command `$("#hot-network-questions").hide();` ~ *thanks to previous answers*

   - > IF: it’s the first time you are using it
   - ELSE: `up-arrow` to issue the same command issued previously

Console log history stays intact with Safari restart

Answer (score 2):

I have uBlock Origin installed in Firefox but never created any custom filters for it previously.
Inspired by @user1993 I now have the following rules (uBlock icon > Open the dashboard > My filters):

```
stackoverflow.com###hot-network-questions > ul > li:has(div[title="Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange"])
stackoverflow.com###hot-network-questions > ul > li:has(div[title="Role-playing Games Stack Exchange"])
stackoverflow.com###hot-network-questions > ul > li:has(div[title="Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange"])
stackoverflow.com###hot-network-questions > ul > li:has(div[title="Movies & TV Stack Exchange"])
stackoverflow.com###hot-network-questions > ul > li:has(div[title="Puzzling Stack Exchange"])
stackoverflow.com###hot-network-questions > ul > li:has(div[title="Arqade"])
stackoverflow.com###hot-network-questions > ul > li:has(div[title="Worldbuilding Stack Exchange"])
```

Comment: Just done this myself. It's unfortunate, though understandable, that *cosmetic* filters such as this can't be made global. But a quick copy-paste and change `stackoverflow` to `stackexchange` in one set will cover all other SE sites as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Anti-distractor for StackExchange](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/anti-distractor-for-stack/ibbknnfapdceeimnbmfhmjfolmifcmcf) is another extension you can use which allows you to hide all of the following:

[image: a checkbox-list of things you can hide from the stack exchange sites]

Comment: Also available for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/ad-for-se ;
Another approach: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/focused-stackexchange