# How to hide entire sidebar except for question stats

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hot-questions, sidebar

There's already a question on [how to hide the "Hot Network Questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222721/how-to-avoid-hot-network-questions-on-the-sidebar) from the sidebar on all Stack Exchange sites. The most popular answer suggests adding `###hot-network-questions` to your adblocker's filter options.

While this works great, afterwards I still see distracting chatroom and newsletter ads as well as "Linked" and "Related" questions. Is there a way to hide all of these as well so that nothing except the top sidebar div for question stats remains?

Also, is there any chance that Stack Exchange might make the sidebar configurable from one's own user profile at some point in the future?

Comment: Its worth remembering those things, to an extent, help drive traffic elsewhere on the site and the network. Not that likely they'll enable disabling it. Also, SE typically has minimal switches and toggles for user side options.

Comment: If you'd like to hide elements of the sidebar, you're stuck using user scripts. We won't be implementing settings to configure what you want to see there.

Answer (score 2):

Create a user style....

As far as I can see, every section inside the sidebar is inside a `<div>` (most have the `.module` class, but not ads, so easiest to just target the `<div>`). The question stats section has the class `.question-stats`. So putting that together to hide every section except the question stats is easy enough...

```
#sidebar div:not(.question-stats) {
    display: none;
}
```

Note, this will hide everything in the sidebar on all pages though (including tag pages and probably other pages where you don't want everything hidden). The body tag has a class that identifies the page type so you can use that to limit what pages this applies to if you'd like. This limits it to question pages for example...

```
.question-page #sidebar div:not(.question-stats) {
    display: none;
}
```

....As for Stack Exchange making this configurable; HNQs are an important part of driving traffic to other parts of the network and distracting users less is likely not a very high priority. So it's probably not going to happen.