# Is "hotness" the best way of sorting linked questions in the sidebar?

Tags: discussion, sorting, linked-questions

When viewing [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) (question score 4042), the "Linked questions" are sorted by hotness, rather than votes.

This means that [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) (question score 2067) isn't listed under linked questions (it is listed under "Related questions"), and [How do you clone an Array of Objects in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) (question score 237) isn't listed in either linked questions or related questions. You have to click on the "Linked questions" link to see them.

By contrast, [Create deep copy in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966926/create-deep-copy-in-angular-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) (question score 2, asked almost a year ago) is listed under linked questions.

Is "hotness" the best way to sort linked questions?