# Send a notification to mods (and 10k users?) when questions go "hot"

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, notifications, 10k-tools, hot-questions

> **Editor's note:** This is not a duplicate of [Now you can know if a question really hit the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324641/now-you-can-know-if-a-question-really-hit-the-hnq). This asks for a *notification* when a question hits HNQ; the revision history item mentioned in the other post does *not* satisfy this request.

On smaller sites, questions that make the network-wide "hot questions" list receive disproportionate amounts of traffic and, sadly, comments and answers we'd like to monitor rather closely.
Also, these questions should be cleaned up to be as presentable as possible (choice of title, formatting, spelling, obsolete or spurious comments, ...).

Currently, there is no way to know that a question is "hot" besides noticing the effects and checking the list on stackexchange.com. This is rather unsatisfying.

Please let moderators (and maybe 10k?) know when a question goes "hot" instantly, via inbox notification. We already have the small diamond which notifies us of (more or less) important things; one message more every few days would fit in nicely there.

Comment: This would help soooo much! Good shout,

Comment: It might fit inside the "Moderator tools" (the ones available when you have the privilege), but I'm not sure if people check that one often enough.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I don't think so. My first thought was the "Links" page of the moderator tools with a simple list, but a live notification is more reliable.

Comment: Worldbuilding frequently has multiple questions in the HNQ list, this wouldn't really be very helpful to us at all.

Comment: @TimB How so? Because you don't usually want/have to act on the event, or because you would not want too frequent notifications?

Comment: Both to be honest. We already get "more than 10 answers" auto flags popping up nearly every day to ignore. (Our community is good about flagging posts that actually need action and we get a lot of high answer-count questions). Wouldn't really want to add more.

Comment: @TimB Fair enough. For us, 10 answers is way past the point of "somebody gotta do something!!". User flags are rare, but even if they come they only tell me "here's a crappy answer", not "be aware that this question may get lots of traffic of people who don't know our customs".

Comment: Normally the view count is a good guide as to HNQ. When I scan the list of new posts if one suddenly starts racking up way more views then usually that's HNQ.

Comment: SE team seems to be [reluctant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238445/add-an-audit-log-to-record-when-particular-question-enters-and-leaves-hot-list#comment781671_238531) about exposing stuff like that: "It would amount to little more than a tool to feed speculation and paranoia..."

Comment: Maybe let the OP know, as well? ....I'd like to know when *my* questions go hot.

Comment: Closely related: (My [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289172/164541) to) the question *Encourage active users to edit Hot Questions, especially titles*.  In the answer I propose putting hot questions in a review queue and/or issuing notifications about them.

Comment: FWIW, `https://stackexchange.com/` has an RSS feed for hot questions. It should be easy to monkey some tool together that monitors that feed and sends notifications in some way.

Comment: related: [Hide Hot Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166652/hide-hot-questions) and [Filtering “hot” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions)

Comment: Does “when” mean “before”?

Comment: With the new feature allowing mods to remove posts from the HNQ list, this could be really helpful for them, I imagine. I agree with Shokhet about pinging the OP as well. 10k might be nice to have in tools, but I don’t see a benefit to pinging them.

Comment: @neverMind9 At the time, I didn't care about _preventing_ a question from showing up. I wanted to know once it _did_ show up so I could be quick to respond to the inevitable low-quality comment and answer storm. Now, I think that both would be nice: one before so we can clean up the candidate, and then after so we can monitor the incoming traffic.

Comment: I see @Raphael. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 32):

I would like to see this in the question page itself. Since the data already exists, it's not like the hotness points would have to be calculated every page view.

I imagine something like this:

> [image]

With a tooltip showing hotness points, same as the title tooltip  in the existing list.

Comment: You want to disqualify your self as an UX expert? ;)

Comment: @rene right on spot! :P

Comment: I assume "HOT!" was meant to be blinking.

Comment: @Fundamental that could have been interesting test to see how many downvotes I can get... :D

Comment: @Fundamental Probably cursive or comic sans too!

Comment: @bjb568 maybe glitter? http://i.stack.imgur.com/HPQZS.gif :D

Comment: this feature may need to be configurable per site, as there may be sites where moderators will find it useless and annoying

Comment: @gnat Since it's mostly to explain possible sudden raise in traffic on the question, the information, shown below "asked, viewed, active" in the right panel, would be in the right place and still not disturbing anybody. As well, a 10k tool could be there to list all recent hot questions, like it lists deletions for instance, and it could appear in the question's history, like tweets do.

Comment: @yo' I think that at most sites, particularly smaller ones, this would be convenient, useful and welcome. My concern was mostly about how it would be at Stack Overflow - per my observations, it is much different from the rest of the SE network in the way how their hot questions are handled by system and perceived by site community. I primarily would like some sort of a "safety switch" to keep this feature on sites where it is wanted and needed if it turns out that SO folks don't like it on their site

Comment: I've used this idea for [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252310/260841) - hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ lol, not at all! :)

Comment: A very similar suggestion has been made in [Encourage active users to edit Hot Questions, especially titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286248/164541).

Comment: Which software have you used to create the image? (The _“hot_” text).

Comment: @neverMind Paint.NET

Answer (score 15):

I've made a userscript using @ShadowWizard's idea of how this could be implemented.

[image]

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SE - is question hot?
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A
// @version      1.0
// @description  Adds a message if the current question is in the top 30 most recent questions
// @author       ᔕᖺᘎᕊ (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A)
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @require      https://cdn.rawgit.com/camagu/jquery-feeds/master/jquery.feeds.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
$('#qinfo').after('<div id="feed"></div>');

$('#feed').feeds({
    feeds: {
        se: 'http://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions'
    },
    xml: true,
    entryTemplate: '<p></p>',
    loadingTemplate: '<div></div>',
    preprocess: function(feed) {
        if (document.URL == this.xml.find('link').attr('href')) {
            addStuff();
        }
    }
});

function addStuff() {
    $('#feed').html('<p>In the top 30 most recent hot network questions!</p>');
    $('#question-header').prepend("<div title='this question is in the top 30 most recent hot network questions!' style='float:right; -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); transform: rotate(30deg); font-size: xx-large; color: red;'>HOT<div>");
}
```

You can use this script by installing my [SE Optional Features userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features).

As SE *does not* provide hotness scores or hot network questions via the API, I've used their feed to get the information; but there's a catch - the feed only lists the top ***30 most recent*** hot-network questions! So it might not work for older questions :(

Comment: It would probably make sense to remove the "%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A" slug from your `@namespace` and `@author` URIs, for in case you ever to decide your username on Stack Exchange. (Not that the URIs will stop working if you _do_ change your username, but it seems better to use a name-agnostic URI.)

Comment: This does not really resolve my request (for that, we'd need at least an indicator in the question list), but thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

As per [Now you can know if a question really hit the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324643), this is now possible and implemented by Stack Exchange. There are now events in a post's revision history, slightly modified from the post above:

[image]

And also in the timeline, as a history event:

[image]

While it's not so obvious as mentioned in the accepted answer, perhaps not to annoy other people, it is at least shown somewhere and that's something!

Comment: That's good for diagnosis, but unfortunately not as an alarm system.

Answer (score 2):

There is a related question [How to add HNQ to chat room feed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313353/295232) where user @rene describes an RSS feed containing Hot Network Questions. It has options to filter by site, e.g. https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/chess.stackexchange.com would contain all HNQs from Chess Stack Exchange.

There it's discussed as a way of posting HNQs in a chatroom, but of course you can use the RSS feed in your own reader to get notified of new Hot Network Questions on a specific site.

Comment: Nice workaround, thanks!