# Popular question with popular answer and votes for closure

Tags: discussion, support, hot-questions

I have answered this question with 1.8k views, 16 upvotes (on Biology SE that's quite good) and counting. My answer is well-received (21 upvotes, accepted). Now people are voting for question closure based on off-topicness. Of course it's totally up to them to vote whatever they want, but still I am wondering -

1. Shouldn't questions be protected that receive so much positive attention? Don't the masses have something to say as well? I mean wouldn't ~20 upvotes weigh more than five folks who think it's off-topic? Of course these numbers may be regarded as ridiculously low among Overflow folks and the likes, but to me they are huge nonetheless :)
2. Am I right that protecting a question will not help me? that is just for spammy answers and comments, rigt?
3. Lastly, can I flag a question like this and ask for moderator protection?

Comment: Votes don't really matter. Btw, 16 votes is not a lot. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read

Comment: @Mysticial - look at my question - I am apologizing for the absolute votes. This is comparable to journal absolute impact factor versus within-discipline relative impact factor :) Biology SE is not big, hence the numbers dwindle. Relatively, however, i.e. to me - it does matter. It's all relative

Comment: Popular != on topic. Popular != suitable.

Comment: So, you are OK with leaving off-topic, unsuitable content on the site? So long as it is popular? Do you realize that's a [broken window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory)?

Comment: @Oded - of course within limits. The question is put off-topic as homework. You're probably right and I should not bother

Comment: this question is currently being rotated in [meta-tag:hot-questions] list. This typically leads to anomalous upvoting, see eg [Prevent questions on Hot List from being upvoted by casual visitors (only rep is from association bonus)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238420/165773). For a more general view on this, refer SE blog article:  [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

Comment: @gnat - aha. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you. I understand and will let matters take their course. You are right.

Comment: ...as for flagging for mod attention, see recent feature request: [Let mods (and 10k?) know when questions go “hot”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245390/165773)

Comment: @gnat - point taken. Thanks for helping here

Comment: another, closely related question: [At smaller sites, penalize hot questions having 3-4 close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237391/165773). "Indiscriminately advertising questions that are on their way to closure... hurts site community morale and dilutes the Stack Exchange brand..."

Comment: @Oded and gnat. Please understand. I am not OK with leaving off-topic questions and I take closing seriously myself. I am, however, also not OK with questions being closed on questionable grounds such as 'off topic because it is homework", when the question is clearly a curiosity based question. I think 'homework' is being (ab)used too often to close valuable questions. In general I think newbies are treated too harshly and in case of a much upvoted question I feel frustrated now and then. I understand and respect your policies, but closing is often a subjective matter.

Comment: Pure popularity doesn't save a question, in this case though I really don't see why the question has to be closed. There is still no real consensus on the homework close reason.

Comment: @MadScientist- thanks. I guess that is my point. Closing a question on questionable grounds is one thing, but one with upvotes and accepted answer is another.

Comment: my only point is that referring to [flash in the pan voting/views](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/615/168) on a hot question like one you asked about is _very_ wrong way to justify it being useful or on-topic. If you want a solid, helpful discussion on it, you better drop this score / views stuff and refer solely to question text - and you better do this on Biology meta, because different sites have different norms on what kind homework questions are acceptable and what aren't

Comment: @gnat,  got it. Point being I wanted an objective opinion, as discussions have been raging quite a while on BioSE. Nonetheless it resulted in yet another explosive discussion... I think the homework issue may indeed be the hidden core of the question, which is indeed site specific, but another mine field at Bio

Comment: If you have a problem with "off-topic -- homework," the place to deal with it is on Biology Meta, not by questioning the closure of a specific question. Ask a Meta Biology question, and see what happens.

Comment: @Shokhet - I used it as an example only and specifically left out a link to the answer as I was curious to what people thought of the general issue. That's all. And yes, I will think twice before going to Meta again :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Shouldn't questions be protected that receive so much positive attention?

No, they shouldn't. That's a slippery slope. You start with one, popular off-topic question. Then comes another one - not so popular, so it gets closed.

Cue complaints - "Why was that other one allowed? This one is just like it!".

Rules are there for a reason - if they are not enforced, equally, they cause [problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory).

> Am I right that protecting a question will not help me? that is just for spammy answers and comments, rigt?

Yes, you are correct. And yes, mostly to protect against spam content (or other non-useful content).

> Lastly, can I flag a question like this and ask for moderator protection?

You *can*, but more likely than not, a moderator would close/delete the post if it is off-topic.