# Non-edit revisions in iOS app don't have any time stamp

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, revisions-list

The [revisions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/245390/revisions) on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245390/let-mods-and-10k-know-when-questions-go-hot) is showing a good example to what I mean:

> [image]

As you can see, no way to know when each action took place.

Worth adding the way it's showing in the site:

> [image]

Can this please be fixed so that we can see when each action happened?

Comment: But... it looks so pretty right now... I guess

Comment: Also that bounty history looks mighty suspicious.

Comment: @Brian lol, all legit. gnat is not my sock. (he's just very stubborn when it comes to stuff he want to see done ;))

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3.7, shipping towards the end of January.

For good measure, revision list links will also open natively rather than in a web view.

Comment: Awesome, totally forgot about this to be honest!