# Exact information about the start of a bounty or answers posted since then

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties

Although the rules for bounty assignment are clear, it is not easy to see what answer (if any) would get if the bounty was auto-assigned (assuming there is no accepted answer).

For the auto assignment, you have to know whether the answer was created after the bounty was created, and for that you have to AFAIK calculate back from the X days mentioned in:

> This question has an open bounty worth +100 reputation from Altruist ending in 3 days.
>
> This question has not received enough attention.

I have not found an exact start date-time stamp that I could compare with the creation date of answers, to see if the answer was created after the bounty was placed and calculating backwards in days is cumbersome and not very accurate.

Can it be made more clear which answers might receive the bounty on auto-assigment? E.g. by implementing one the following:

- exact start information be added e.g. while hovering over the "X days"
- mark the answers that are eligible with some text

Or is there some way to obtain this information that I missed?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the time the bounty has started (you can by hovering over the *ending ...* text), you got a time to put next to the information from the timeline page. This will allow you to see which answers are eligible for the bounty.

Here is an example [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247195/245360) (a random question with a bounty):

The bounty box shows the start time:

[image: bounty box]

Then open the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/247195/timeline):

[image: timeline]

You can see the time line. The last answer was added after the bounty started, the first didn't.

Comment: For some reason the hovering did not work on the bountied question I was looking at, that is why I proposed that as a possible solution. I refreshed the page and it is working now.

Comment: Okay, so you have all you need to get the analysis done. Now you could still argue if it needs to be more visible or not...