# During bounty period, increase understanding of which answers are eligible for auto-awarding

Tags: feature-request, design, bounties, auto-acceptance

Based on the confusion present in many questions on various metas, most recently exemplified on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296327/why-didnt-the-answerer-get-my-bounty?noredirect=1#comment206660_296327), it seems that even those who have a reasonably good understanding of bounty mechanics can still easily be confused by minor technicalities, resulting in rep being misallocated or lost. This is probably because relatively few users will routinely post bounties, so nearly all users will be re-learning much of the process each time, leading to more mistakes. With large amounts of rep at stake, and a systematic lack of any way to undo anything in the bounty process, any mistakes become far more serious than most other areas of site functionality.

Is there a way to systematically reduce that confusion in the UI, especially around what circumstances will allow an answer to receive the auto-award?

Comment: [Related post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258565/) on how you can extract some of this data now.

Comment: I disagree with the premise. If the bounty setter knows which answer to reward, they should do that. If they don't, there is no use telling them about automatic awards. Ideally, they would not even know there are any automatic awards, and assume they have to award the bounty themselves.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato: While [I do agree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296327/?#comment204343_296327) that bounty posters should manually award whenever possible, I disagree that there is no need to understand the automatic awarding process. One might, for example, mistakenly assume that the auto-award gives the full value; the suggested tooltip in my answer corrects that misconception. Or one might wish to ensure that, given that *no* answer is actually currently suitable, at least the least worst answer gets the auto-bounty. Like it or not, auto-awards are an important part of bounties.

Answer (score 4):

#### Display an indicator beside each answer that is eligible for the auto-award

It seems like it would be straightforward enough to make the bounty award slot do double-duty as an indicator of whether an answer can have half the bounty auto-awarded. The indicator could be in the form of, say, a dashed outline and a dark gray +½N for an N-rep bounty; these would be substantially darker than the normal faint gray outline button that allows manual awarding, and hovering would act much like the usual button, except that the tooltip would (also?) mention something like this: "If this answer has the highest score at the end of the bounty period and no answer is manually awarded the bounty after the grace period ends, it will receive +½N rep automatically. Or click here to award +N now." (Or a little shorter, perhaps by using specific timestamps and rolling it together.)

This way, scrolling down the page would quickly show the relevant set of answers; if an answer doesn't have that indicator, it won't be eligible! It would probably be best to tweak the non-eligible tooltip to mention this as well, e.g. "This answer is not currently eligible for an automatic bounty award, but you can manually award +N by clicking here."

These indicators would only be displayed to the bounty placer, just like the award button is now.