# Link to "More Hot Questions" from within the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button, hot-questions

The Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ shows the hottest 50 questions. Cool, but the [full list](https://stackexchange.com/questions) is showing 100 questions.

Can you please add link to "more hot questions" in the bottom of the list in the MultiCollider same way there is "more inbox messages" already in the inbox tab?

Comment: oh no... [not yet please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192046/165773 "Carthago delenda est"). :) More-hot-questions in collider => more "hotness lemmings" to break good posts

Comment: @gnat not asking to add all 100 to the collider, just a link to those interested to see all and too lazy to go all the way.

Comment: hmm further increasing exposure to "those interested... and too lazy" to me looks like carrying just more risks associated with known issues of [Answers quality in hot questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5543/31260)

Comment: @gnat each and his own, IMO increasing exposure is always a good thing. :)

Comment: that's probably because you never tried to fight with editing / [commenting](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/177875/why-is-the-sudden-increase-in-number-of-git-submitters-on-debian-popcon-graph-in#comment340223_177901) against garbage answers (and sympathy upvotes to these) that come quicker than you can handle _"...there are just too many new voters and commenters to get things going as designed... So comes next and next and next round of garbage answers, bumping the question, bringing mindless upvotes, over and over and over again..."_

Comment: @gnat so we better sweep it under the carpet, hide the shame until it's fixed? May be so, but it doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: wel it's probably can be called that way. Other way to describe it is "protect your own users from scale ...human interaction, many to many interaction, doesn't blow up like a balloon..." ([A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://www.shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html "quote source")) One can probably say that Meta Filter guys at referred article sweep things under carpet by closing their registration page in _times of hotness_, other would say they protect their community and interaction from getting blown up by unhealthy scaling. You pick the way you prefer to describe it

Comment: +1 (I was unaware of it until [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210877/145673)) but I guess you need to update this request for the new layout.

Comment: @MartinSmith that was already suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209775/152859). Better close this one as dupe or "can't reproduce anymore".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Thanks. I'll upvote that one too then!