# Can we see the "hot network questions" during search results?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, hot-questions

I was going to add my request to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209775/extend-the-new-hot-questions-sidebar) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209956/please-return-the-hot-question-dropdown-to-most-pages) post at first, but I figured it would be clearer if I'd give it its own post.

I keep track of new StackOverflow posts trough a search query like this:

[image]

I do this for a few reasons:

- I dislike the yellow background that comes with tags you have favorited in the portal
- I don't wish to see questions from tags I don't know anything about
- The search bar has the instant notification when new questions appear
- The portal sorts on activity, I want it sorted by time of asking

However, with the dropdown gone for "hot" questions it is only visible from the portal. Which I don't use.

Can this also be added for the search results page? Who uses those related tags anyway.. Maybe give the option to choose between related tags and hot questions?