# Replace "Find a Stack Exchange Site" with "Hot Questions"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, top-bar, hot-questions

Unlike the vast majority of the posts I've seen here, I actually do quite like the new top bar, for the most part.  (Subjectively speaking, though, I'm very partial to dark themes; obviously it all depends on the person.)  My only real issue with it which significantly affects my StackOverflow/StackExchange experience is that it has no access at all to the "Hot Questions" list which was, for me at least, one of the primary ways of interacting throughout the StackExchange community and finding interesting things happening.

My suggestion/request is to remove the "Find a Stack Exchange Site" feature on the drop down and replace it with the old "Hot Questions" list and rankings.  Having the full list of Stack Exchange sites is bulky and unnecessary anyway, and the list is quite long.  All it does is desensitize the user to all that information and train them to ignore everything once they hit the little Search bar.

I actually like the idea of being able to search for a relevant StackExchange site like that, but the entire list is bulky and unnecessary.  I think removing it and putting the "Hot Questions" back there would be a change in the right direction, would improve the user experience, and would stop a good many of the complaints I've seen on Meta since the change.

Note that I did see [this related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209956/please-return-the-hot-question-dropdown-to-most-pages), but all it really contained was a complaint and a "I don't know how you are going to fix this, but fix it".  I am offering what I think to be a reasonable suggestion and alternative to the current design.

Comment: Please do not do this.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Hot network questions are going to be placed in other areas, we just had to break up things into manageable chunks with the new top bar rollout

Comment: I disagree, the list of sites is useful. But the two aspects (open yourself to other sites and open yourself to other questions) could easily live next to each other.

Comment: And while we're at it, we could have a single menu with submenus for the site list and the hot questions, and for the inbox and the achievements as well. Hmmm...

Comment: @Gilles Fair enough.  But could you explain *why* you think having that huge lists of sites is useful on that drop down?  Do you actually browse for random Stack Exchange sites that much that you don't already visit?

Comment: @JeffGohlke In my case, no, but when it comes to participating on multiple SE sites and to knowing what sites exist, I'm rather an outlier case. Still, I do expect to use that menu now and then. For people who don't know what sites exist, that menu is useful, it's more convenient than having to 1. discover and 2. go to http://stackexchange.com/sites.

Comment: @Gilles Oh, sure.  I'm not arguing that it has NO use.  (That's why I'm saying, hey, leave the Search bar if you want.)  I'm just saying that the argument that it's more useful or will be more used than the Hot Questions seems facetious at best.

Answer (score 9):

I agree we should put the hot questions back where it was in the top bar.

In my experience, the Hot Questions thing was great being so easily accessible. I've learnt a lot of new things and also found out about new stack communities just by checking it every now and then.

I know it's now on the main page, but I think it's less discoverable plus you got to purposefully go to that page. A lot of the times, I check the Hot questions, it's kind of an impulsive "oh i wonder what other questions I can see" type act.

The All sites bar is not as useful, because most of the time if I'm moving to another site that I commonly go to, it's far faster for me to just Alt D and start typing it into my url bar then to grab the mouse to open the tab and try to find it out of the list.

Answer (score 3):

We are planning a big expansion of hot network questions to other pages.

I agree that the homepage sidebar isn't enough.  I'm status-declining this specific request, but look for hot network question changes in the next couple weeks.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It may be outside the scope of this question, but can I ask what the rationale for having the entire list of Stack Exchange sites crammed into that drop down is and why you guys want to keep it there?  I'm trying to wrap my head around the value that adds from a UX standpoint.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Tough to elaborate completely in a comment, but we'd like to move away from isolated communities and encourage people to jump around to different sites that might interest them. I think the site switcher makes it easier to do this (plus, you have to have a way to switch sites, and how would you do it otherwise?). Also, hot questions is a discovery feature not a navigation feature and really doesn't belong in the top bar. And finally, the click through rate on homepage sidebar is way higher than it was in the top bar.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm actually really surprised the click-through rate is higher with the new layout, but that alone is reason enough to leave it and means that my subjective point of view is the outlier with regards to this.  The only thing I'd say is that the Hot Questions, it seems to me, offer much more encouragement to explore different parts of Stack Exchange than just a flat list of all the different sites, if that really is the end goal.  The questions catch the eye with things that are, by definition, interesting to a large population.

Comment: I would think the odds of someone just scrolling through all 100+ entries and randomly seeing "English Language & Usage" and being interested in it is much lower than someone seeing a very "hot" question title like [this one about pirate talk](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/what-is-the-factual-basis-for-pirate-speech-did-pirates-really-say-things-li) and being intrigued enough to go there.

Answer (score 1):

You have the list on [every main and meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) in the right column. So it's even more accessible now, [which is the intention](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/). Do you need more?

Comment: I completely disagree that that is more accessible, as it requires you to navigate to a certain page in order to access it.  Before, you could look at it on any page, regardless of where you were on Stack Overflow.  There are also many people who don't even naturally visit the main page at all to begin with.

Comment: You also can't see what the score of the "hot questions" is when you look at them there.  Used to be you could look at the list, see that the top Hot Question had a score of 40, and think "Hm, SE is having a kind of slow day."  But then you could see a question with a score of 400+ and be like "Damn, this must be interesting!  Maybe I should check it out!"  The entire sidebar "solution" is shoddy and not very well thought out, to be honest.

Comment: @JeffGohlke **ad 2nd comment)** I think that having the score there is a good idea, and a reasonable feature request (really and seriously, it sounds good, and as I see the "Related" panel on the right here, it makes much sense). **ad 1st comment)** You seem to have a point. To me, it does not, and I like this new feature of the topbar. Another suggestion: The "Hot Network Questions" right panel would have "see more", which would bring you to a devoted network-wide site with the hot questions. People like you could then bookmark that link. As well, one would see a bit of the Qs text, so nice!

Comment: Nice points.  Not quite a full solution, but I definitely get what you're saying.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: @JeffGohlke You're welcome. IMHO it's a good compromise. In the future, I would personally vote for customizable topbar, offering like 30 icon-shaped links and used would opt-in up to let's say 5 of them. This could be one such link :)