# Shorten or remove the Related Tags and Hot Network Questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, hot-questions

**EDIT: I don't feel this way anymore about this topic. I actually like the tags there and the hot network questions now. It was just an inconvenience having them there when I was adding my ignore tags. But I like them there now, so please no more down votes. Thanks.**

---

Firstly I'll discuss the `Related Tags` section.

The `Related Tags` seems to be a bunch of tags that I don't need to see in the right sidebar. From my experiments, it seems it only really appear when you're browsing questions, so it shows like 20 different related tags. I don't have any use for it what so ever, and I'm sure a lot of other people would agree that they have no use for it either.

I would like it to be removed. But if that is asking for too much, **it should at least be shortened exactly how the "Ignored Tags" section is**. Where it only takes up 2 lines, and then you can click to view all of them.

---

Secondly I'll discuss the `Hot Network Questions` section. This is not useful to me at all. It reminds me of "popular videos on youtube". When all the popular videos are not anything you really care to watch.

So I would like to see the `Hot Network Questions` removed too. Or at least shortened to a limit of 3 questions and then the option to click to view more.

---

If none of those work for you, my last request would be to at least give us the option of shorting those sections by clicking a button or being able to remove it all together.

Comment: Relevant to "Hot Questions" size: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209775/212780

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use "related tags" all the time, **and so should you.**

Ok, maybe you shouldn't, but you should at least understand why they are *there*.

Stack Overflow doesn't have any sort of explicit tag hierarchy. Folks have asked for such a thing, and been told "no"... Because a hierarchy is very constraining - every specific tag has to be contained within a more general tag, but not *multiple* more general tags; rarely are topics so neatly related.

But it *is* still useful to identify relationships between tags. If I'm studying up on [msmq](/questions/tagged/msmq) I can see how the topic breaks down by scanning that list; maybe I want to check out the problems that folks using [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msmq%20c%2b%2b) encounter - click the link, and I've narrowed my search to questions in just those two tags. And best yet, now there's *another* list of related tags on the right - I can keep drilling down as far as I need to!

It's a surprisingly fast and effective way to explore a topic. If it was collapsed, we'd lose that *at a glance* view of how a topic breaks down... And for what? There's nothing else in that sidebar that needs any appreciable amount of space (except for Hot Network Questions, which you also hate).

If you *really* don't like them, they'd be fairly trivial to hide entirely with a userscript... But I recommend you stop fearing what you don't understand and learn to use the site more effectively.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand what there is to gain from that; as I noted, there's nothing below them in the sidebar but the list of hot questions. FWIW, `$("#h-related-tags").parent().hide()` will hide them entirely.