# Vote counts wrong in hot questions

Tags: support, hot-questions

Here is an example from right-now's hot questions list:
[image]

The ServerFault question ([What are the advantages of tape drives?](https://serverfault.com/questions/550763/what-are-the-advantages-of-tape-drives)) actually has 19 votes. The Code Review question (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33851/how-can-i-improve-my-code)? Six. Is this number not a vote count, or is this a bug?

Comment: It is not a vote count

Comment: That's the question's "hotness" rating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the number of votes, it's the question's "hotness" rating. You'll notice each successive answer has a lower score - the "hottest" questions at the topic, descending into the questions that are only warm, or down-right cool.

As for how that rating is determined, see [How are questions in the 'hot' tab selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4766/188613)

And how that formula was decided on, see [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/188613)

There's also been a [ton](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99077/188613) of [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192046/188613) about the [Hot List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84389/188613) and how it could be improved.