# Why can I not include small pictures (or labels) in a question title?

Tags: discussion, images, title

## Background

There has been no question I have seen on any of the stack exchanges that includes the use of a small picture or label in the question title. I understand pictures are discouraged in the body of a question [for many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) But in a question about what certain labels mean, like this one about [Android folder labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829732/what-do-these-android-studio-folder-symbols-mean) the whole reason of the question is about a labels themselves.  Thus a more helpful title here would include these pictures outright for clarity, instead of an ambiguous "What do these mean?"

## Question

Why are pictures not allowed for question titles, even for ones where the question depends on a picture?

Comment: Because it would be a mess: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237125/can-we-get-markdown-support-in-questions-title-field

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An image isn't searchable. Words are.

You should be considering titling your question in a descriptive way (and avoid asking multiple questions at once!):

> What is this Android folder icon with a small yellow circle in the lower right corner?
>   What is this Android folder icon with a set of three vertical bars in the lower right corner?

... these titles actually tell someone what you're looking at without requiring them to be able to see the image.

You're absolutely encouraged to include the image in your question if that's the only way you can include it (you don't have the actual URL of the icon itself) as supporting and illustrative information. There's a huge difference between posting an image of your code (which users can't copy and paste and play with) and posting an image of... an image.

On top of this, images in question titles are distracting and could be a huge avenue for abuse. These are things we want to avoid. Question pages should be clean and neat, images and other wonky text in titles can be annoying and confusing and detract from other questions in the list.

Comment: I got downvoted on both questions when I split them up.