# Spoilers in the sidebar are annoying

Tags: discussion, spoilers

The `HOT NETWORK QUESTIONS` section in the sidebar shows a lot of Marvel Universe questions from the movies SE site right now. [Some of the titles](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33981/how-did-ultron-come-to-be-in-the-sceptre) spoil (little) parts of the story. This is annoying. What can be done about it?

This is a significant problem because those spoilers are shown to literally millions of people all over the SE network.

Also: It is the aspiration of Stack Exchange to eventually reach pretty much everyone on the planet with their network of sites. Is it their secret diabolic plan to build a gigantic spoiler distribution machine?

Comment: The questions which contain spoilers in the titles would have to be identified somehow so the Hot Topics scripts could exclude them. Perhaps specific sites such as *movies* could have a "spoiler" tag which Hot Topics could use as a basis to exclude?

Comment: The title is also a problem on the main site (if you were to click on movies.se, hot network question filtering doesn't prevent spoilers there). The HNQ part is a symptom of spoilers in the title not being obscured.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - the "original" question doesn't have an answer. Yet.

Comment: @DeerHunter absolutely correct.  But that doesn't matter on Meta.  We don't need the same discussion over and over again.  So it is considered better to confine duplicate topics to the same post.

Comment: @James That's entirely unnecessary, since those sites have an applied an working "no spoilers in titles" policy anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau good, so when will they start to apply and enforce that policy?

Comment: @usr They are, all the time. Of course it needs people to notice and edit the violations, but well, that's the case with every policy (including some strange special spoiler tag).