# Choose which sites to show in the "feed"

Tags: feature-request, android-app, hot-questions

I have a `StackExchange` account which I mostly use for `Stack Overflow` (and meta), but I did have some activity on other sites (a comment or two) a long time ago.

I think it's distracting that I still see it on the feed (for example that I'm close to a privilege that I'm not going to reach) and I have no control over it.

I went ahead and removed those sites from the "Your sites" part of the panel on the right, but I still see "hot questions" from them on the main feed.

Comment: @gnat It's related, but i don't think it's the same. I'm talking about sites, and he's talking about types of activities.

Comment: @gnat that's unrelated both to the "feed"  and the android app.

Comment: [Filtering “hot” questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions)

Comment: @gnat that too.

Comment: how's that? other than you want it in android app, I see no difference

Comment: @gnat it's in the android app and not the main site. It's in the main "feed" and not the "hot questions". It's replies, reputation and unanswered questions, not just hot questions. The only thing similar is that it's about some kind of filtering.

Comment: keep in mind that you have many sites, but only one app. when i go to SO i don't see unanswered questions on the skeptics site. I do on the app.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you