# Block communities from "Hot Network Questions"

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Give the option to users to not see questions from some communities on the "Hot Network Questions" tab.

Comment: I wrote [a little Chrome extension](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272128/134300) to do this for myself. It's not the most polished, but it's not too bad.